# Rounding issue in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following problem with percentages calculations and rounding the results.

If I use `Math.ceil`:

```
var total = 66666;
var test1 = Math.ceil(60 / 100 * total);
var test2 = Math.ceil(23.5 / 100 * total);
var test3 = Math.ceil(14 / 100 * total);
var test4 = Math.ceil(2.5 / 100 * total);
```

Then `test1 + test2 + test3 + test4 = 66664`

If I use `ParseInt`:

```
var total = 66666;
var test1 = parseInt(60 / 100 * total);
var test2 = parseInt(23.5 / 100 * total);
var test3 = parseInt(14 / 100 * total);
var test4 = parseInt(2.5 / 100 * total);
```

Then `test1 + test2 + test3 + test4 = 66668`

I try to rewrite my script from Python to Javascript and in Python I didn't have any problem like this.

Comment: It's the opposite: `Math.ceil` rounds upwards, so you get `66668`. `parseInt` converts to string and parses the part before the dot to a number again, so like `Math.trunc` (but slower) you get `66664`.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you round your numbers, those will have some error. When you sum those numbers, the errors can cancel each other, or add up. If you don't like that, don't round.

Comment: Indeed.  You're comparing apples and oranges - `parseInt` vs `Math.floor` would be a better comparison.  Here's the [performance difference](http://jsperf.com/math-floor-vs-math-round-vs-parseint/55)

Comment: @JamesThorpe Only for positive numbers. `parseInt` behaves more like `Math.trunc` (except with `-0`).

Comment: @Oriol Yes, thanks - negative numbers didn't cross my mind with this question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you read the [**doc**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Summary) how `parseInt` works you release where the problem is:

> The parseInt() function parses a string argument and returns an
>   integer of the specified radix (the base in mathematical numeral
>   systems).
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> parseInt(string, radix);
> ```
>
> **string**
>
> The value to parse. **If string is not a string, then it is converted to
>   one**. Leading whitespace in the string is ignored.
>
> **radix**
>
> An integer between 2 and 36 that represents the radix (the base in
>   mathematical numeral systems) of the above mentioned string. Specify
>   10 for the decimal numeral system commonly used by humans. Always
>   specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee
>   predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different
>   results when a radix is not specified.
>
> **Description**
>
> **The parseInt function converts its first argument to a string, parses
>   it, and returns an integer or NaN**.

Example:

```
parseInt(2.1) // returns 2
parseInt(2.9) // returns 2 too
parseInt('2.99') // returns 2
```

Also is suggested to pass radix too as argument when call `parseInt`.

To round number in javascript best to use is `Math.round()` function.

**Reference**:

[Math.Round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function accepts a string as its argument, whereas [`Math.ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) accepts a number. Because of this, the `parseInt` lines will interpret a string that looks something like this:

```
parseInt(60 / 100 * total);
// equivalent to: parseInt("39999.6")
```

In doing this, they'll strip off the decimal and return `39999` where the `Math.ceil` calls will return `40000`. This is what accounts for the difference.